# Control Cache Duplicating textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create textboxes based on the amount selected from the drop down list; however say I select 2 it shows the 2 textboxes, and I go and select 3 then the 3 textboxes is added to the other 2 textboxes making it 5 textboxes. I tried null the control cache but one extra textbox seem to always be adding.

```
    protected List<Control> ControlCache
{
    get { return (List<Control>)(Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = (Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] as List<Control>) ?? new List<Control>()); }
    set { Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = value; }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (var control in ControlCache)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        }
    }
    else
        ControlCache = null;
}
protected void ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCount.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
ControlCache = null;
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.MaxLength = 10;

        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        ControlCache.Add(tx);

    }
    }
```

Comment: yes it does have a Remove or Clear function

Comment: Awesome. Call `ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear` before your `for` loop in `ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: ControlCache = null; ControlCache.Add(tx); so i should remove these two lines; when I a post back the textboxes are remove that's I had a cache

Comment: I am not sure what `ControlCache` is - but I am reasonably sure you want to use `ControlCache = new List<Control>()` rather than setting it to `null`.

Comment: in ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged but that wold clear out the textboxes on post back'

Comment: @mjwills; can you assist me please on a second post back instead of showing that amount selected it only shows 1

Comment: @mjwills; I'm still not undertanding